# Xcode failed to download. Use the Purchases page to try again. Xcode 9.3. MacOS High Sierra

Tags: xcode, app-store, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading MacOS to High Sierra, I tried to update Xcode and get this:

> Xcode failed to download. Use the Purchases page to try again

I uninstalled Xcode and try to install again with no success.

I read some tips to solve this but nothing helps...

1. Remove ~/Library/Cookies/com.apple.appstore.plist (no such file)
2. Use AppStore Debug menu... (menu never appears with the command to enable it)

   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
3. Remove contents of /private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.appstore (folder located, contents removed, nothing changes)
4. "wiping all caches, cookies amd such like" (how to do that?)
5. Reset AppStore (uh?)
6. LogOut, quit, restart Mac (done, no changes)
7. Quit AppStore process and try again (done, no changes)
8. Review payment options (done, no changes)

Yes, the drive has enough space

Comment: Same issue tried all above options no luck..plz help

Comment: After I installed the beta version of XCode (can't stop working), today I opened the AppStore and clicked on install again, and to my surprise it worked out...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and finally got this working, however I'm not sure exactly which step made it work, so I'm posting all of them.

From https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245406/how-to-fix-reset-app-store-app-on-mac-osx-el-capitan:

Delete:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore
~/Library/Caches/storeaccount
~/Library/Caches/storeassets
~/Library/Caches/storedownload
~/Library/Caches/storeinappd
```

I didn't have some of those folders, but I did have a couple of extras that looked fishy, so I deleted them too:

```
~/Library/Caches/storeassetd
~/Library/Caches/storedownloadd
```

Run `sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog` *[Note: I did this but I don't think it helped]*

From http://osxdaily.com/2016/10/08/mac-app-store-temp-cache-folder/ (paraphrasing):

1. Quit out of the Mac App Store
2. Open Terminal and run `open $TMPDIR../C/com.apple.appstore/`
3. Hit Return and the `com.apple.appstore` folder will open in the Finder of Mac OS
4. Delete the contents of this folder

And finally:

5. Navigate to `~/Applications` in Finder and move Xcode to the Trash *[Note: This step was necessary for me, but ymmv]*
6. Reboot
7. Launch App Store. Search for Xcode. Install it fresh.

Comment: Files in High Sierra may be diferent from El Capitan, because I did not find any of these files in Caches. 
The other steps I had tried without success

Comment: My problem/solution was also in High Sierra.

Comment: Yes, the link was about El Capitan.  And as I said above, I didn't have some of those folders, but I had additional ones that I deleted. I didn't say that the single El Capitan link was all you needed to do, just that I gleaned some information from it in order to form my answer, which applies to High Sierra.

Comment: thank you very much. this was very helpfull and worked on high sierra.